# How to send individual variables from collected API data to another location

Tags: c#, api, post

I'm trying to collect data from a client through an API.  Eventually sending individual parts of the data that I collected to another project.
So for example I'm collecting an entire data object with id,Name,Status, etc. And I only want the id variable with it's value to be send to another project.
Everything works fine except from the sending part. I still had to paste all related classes to make it easier to understand.
I'm trying to send a list of objects. The problem is that I don't know how to send it the right way. You can see what I tried below. I'm creating my own object named WatchdogDTO which contains only the values that I want to send. Eventually I serialize it to send it to http://localhost:53661/api/Values. Which is another project I use to test if it works. Now it just literally sends the name of the list instead of the actual WatchdogDTO.

This is the data I'm collecting:

```
[
    {
        "id": "200",
        "name": "Kerno (Camera)",
        "hostName": "Amsterdam",
        "status": false,
        "hasCamera": true,
        "cameraStatus": "0",
        "lastSeen": "34324"
    },
    {
        "id": "202",
        "name": "Bassy (Location)",
        "hostName": "Limburg",
        "status": true,
        "hasCamera": false,
        "cameraStatus": "-1",
        "lastSeen": "2344"
    }
]
```

I created a corresponding model:

```
public class ServerStateDto
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HostName { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public bool hasCamera { get; set; }
        public string CameraStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastSeen { get; set; }
    }
```

In the class ApiManager I collect the data above and deserialize it:

```
class ApiManager
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public List<ServerStateDto> CollectWatchdogData()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://classified.Data.net:4802");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/pdf/process/getalldata").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string dto = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<ServerStateDto> model =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServerStateDto>>(dto);
                return model;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is just a general class that calls the functions CollectWatchdogData(); and PostWatchdogData();
    {

```
    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {

        ApiManager x = new ApiManager();
        List<ServerStateDto> returnedData = x.CollectWatchdogData();

        if (returnedData == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        WatchdogApiClient cli = new WatchdogApiClient();
               cli.PostWatchdogData(returnedData);

        return true; 
    }
}
```

This is a model for the object that I'm sending. I only want to send Id from the model above:

```
 public class WatchdogDTO
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

This class actually sends the WatchdogDTO from above to localhost:53661 which is another visual studio project of my which I use to test if the sending works.

```
public class WatchdogApiClient
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //public async void PostWatchdogData(ServerStateDto toSend)
        public async void PostWatchdogData(List<ServerStateDto> toSend)
        {
            //to actually send the data
            WatchdogDTO toActuallySend = new WatchdogDTO()
            {
                id = toSend.ToString()
            };

            //Serialize data to bytestream so it can be sent
            string serializedWatchDogData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toActuallySend);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serializedWatchDogData))
            {
                return;
            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:53661/api/Values", new StringContent(serializedWatchDogData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Encountered an exception during PostAsync in method PostWatchDogData: {ex.Message}");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Eventually the destination of the data has a class and a model aswell to receive the data sent
model:

```
public class WatchdogDTO 
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the sending part, the sending works but the problem is that the value of WatchdogDTO data is the name of the list instead of the actual list with its values.

```
Class to receive the data send:
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void PostWatchdogData([FromBody] WatchdogDTO data)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("Server", "b");
        }
    }
```

How can I send individual parts like for example only the id, or the host name, or the id AND the hostname.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the bunch of code.

Comment: `List<ServerStateDto> toSend` is a collection so you really don't want to use it as is. You can map it using `System.Linq` i.e. `toSend.Select(r => r.Name);` and this will return an `IEnumerable<string>` of the names inside `toSend` then you can serialize that and pass it as parameter to your API request.

Comment: @jegtugado I changed "id = toSend.ToString()"  like you said but I get the following error:
 CS1922 Cannot initialize type 'WatchdogDTO' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Bellesa, change `toSend.ToString()` to `string.Join(",", toSend);`.

Comment: @iSR5 I'm not sure what it did but it build succesfully. 
However at the destination I received the following:
"TMD.LocationServiceWRS.Service.ServerStateDto,TMD.LocationServiceWRS.Service.ServerStateDto"
I'm assuming these are the 2 objects which I collected from the API? I expected however it would only send the Id with its value.

Comment: @Bellesa, my bad, I was confused between ServerStateDto and WatchdogDTO. just modify it to this `string.Join(",", toSend.Select(x=> x.Id).ToList())`. this should do it.

Comment: @iSR5 Unfortunately it gives me the same error as before: CS1922 Cannot initialize type 'WatchdogDTO' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: I fixed the problem already using the following line in the function postwachtdogdata(): toActuallySend.id = string.Join(",", toSend.Select(x => x.id).ToArray());